# How to delete (not quarantine) emails from blocked domains using Google's Postini service

Tags: email, g-suite, spam

In Google's Postini service we have a number of domains in our "Blocked Senders" list, messages sent to us from these domains are automatically quarantined as a result.

What we would like to do is just have any messages from the "Blocked Senders" list automatically deleted as they still appear in the daily summary of quarantined messages and are a distraction from genuine emails.

We already know that we don't ever want to read emails from our blocked senders, is there a way we can configure Postini to automatically delete emails from blocked domains either through the "Blocked Senders" list or some other method?

Comment: What does Google say to this question?

Comment: +mailq not sure whether you are asking whether I have Googled this question or not (I have done and it didn't return any useful results) or whether I have contacted Google in terms of raising a support query? Based on past experience where support tickets can be interrupted by the person dealing with them's month long vacation that is my last resort.

Comment: No, not the Google search engine. The Postini support. You pay them for such things.

Comment: +mailq please refer to my comments above. We do pay them; but they are completely useless and most definitely a last resort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been given a response to this outside of Serverfault which I'll replicate here in case anyone else needs to know:

> [from] "Vince Garcia - This can be achieved only via Inbound Content
>   Manager. Create a rule that matches Sender:contains text = e-mail
>   address of sender. Then set Routing to Blackhole."